# how to use eggplant testing tool in android

Tags: android, eggplant

Hi friends
 can anybody give tutorial how to use eggplant testing tool for mobile application in android

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some tutorials for using eggPlant: [Tutorials](http://www.testplant.com/tutorials).
The underlying system that it uses to interact with applications should handle the Android interface just as easily as it does a desktop or web-based application.

Comment: You'll generate the script by recording actions with eggPlant and your application. If you click the "Show detail.." links on the right side of those tutorials it should walk you through the basic operations.